# Discord.py : Can't use normal command and embed in the same program

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot command with an embed. Since I can't have argument when using embeds, I created a `ctx` command instead. However, it does not execute the `ctx` command and I don't get any error. Is there any way to fix this, or a way to use an argument in an embed? The way the embed command works fine. Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='mb!')

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, say):
    await ctx.send(say)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("mb!help"):
        embedhelp=discord.Embed(title="Help menu", color=0x38e907)
        embedhelp.add_field(name="mb!help", value="Show this help menu", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedhelp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by, "Since I can't have argument when using embeds." Because if you made a command called 'help,' added the parameters you needed and sent an embed the same way you are doing now, it would work fine. However, I think the issue thats going on here is that you're triggering the help command that is already built in to Discord.py.

To fix this, simply add to your code

```py
bot.remove_command('help')
```

Hopefully this helps (: